# Probability Theory: What can you say about $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ as n goes to infinity?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The question comes from a graduate-level probability theory class.

We have real-valued random variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with density functions
\begin{align}
f_{X_n}(x)=\begin{cases}
e^n  & x\in(0, e^{-n}(1-1/n))\\
1/x^2 & x\in (n, \infty)
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
Assuming that $X_1, X_2,\ldots$  are independent, what can we say about the probability distribution of $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ as n goes to infinity?

Comment: Notice that $$\Bbb{P}(X_n \geq n) = \int_{n}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{1}{n}$$ and we have $\sum_{n\geq 1} \Bbb{P}(X_n \geq n) = \infty$. What can you say about $S_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $$\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant n) = \int_n^\infty \frac1{x^2}\ \mathsf dx = \frac1n, $$ which implies that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n\geqslant n)=\infty. $$ It follows from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma that $$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\, \{X_n\geqslant n\} \right)=1, $$ and hence $$\mathbb P\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n = +\infty \right) = 1. $$